# Matlab arrayfun

Tags: arrays, matlab, function, pi

I do this:

```
A = [pi/2 3*pi/2 3*pi/2 pi];
B = arrayfun(wrapToPi, A);
```

Expecting B:

```
[pi/2 -pi/2 -pi/2 pi]
```

But instead of that, I receive an error message:

```
Not enough input arguments.

Error in wrapToPi (line 13)
q = (lambda < -pi) | (pi < lambda);

Error in PSK (line 19)
x = arrayfun(wrapToPi,indices2);
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: oh, it probably has something to do with your definition of `wrapToPi`

Comment: The function wrapToPi is defined by MatLab. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: ah, apologies, it is not present in my version of matlab, I assumed it was a custom function. In that case, since it is a valid 'single-argument' function, the correct way to call it from an `arrayfun` is via a function-handle, i.e. `arrayfun(@wrapToPi, A)`. Or (as has already been pointed out below), just use the vectorised form of `wrapToPi` directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arrayfun` has nothing to do here.

The correct way of doing that is:

```
A = [pi/2 3*pi/2 3*pi/2 pi];
wrapToPi(A)
```

which gives:

```
ans =

    1.5708   -1.5708   -1.5708    3.1416
```

which is the same as:  `[pi/2 -pi/2 -pi/2 pi]`